# Add extra headers to chrome.downloads.download api

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add extra headers to the `chrome.downloads.download` method but I get always this error:

```
TypeError: Error in invocation of downloads.download(downloads.DownloadOptions options, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'options': Error at property 'headers': Error at index 0: Unexpected property: 'Authorization'.
```

I'm trying to use the authorization header. This is the code, how I can fix it?

```
        browser.downloads.download({
          url: `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/u/${response.data.processed_file}`, 
          saveAs: true, 
          method: 'GET',
          headers: [{'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.$store.getters.userToken}`}]
        }).then( (downloadId) => console.log('Download completed', downloadId) );
```

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#property-options-headers) and use `name`, `value` keys.

Comment: The documentation talk about array of object like I'm doing, what do you mean with `name` and `value`? something like `[{ name: 'Authorization', value: 'Bearer myheader' }]` ?

Comment: The documentation explicitly describes how the object should look like. Your new example is correct.

Comment: ok thank you!now seems working fine